# Prove or disprove that $u=0$ a.e. on $\Bbb R^d$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, measure-concentration, measurable-functions

Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^d$ be an open set. Let $k:\Bbb R^d\to [0,\infty)$ be measurable such that $0\in \operatorname{supp}k$. This implies that $\Omega\subset \Omega_k=\Omega+\operatorname{supp}k$. Recall that [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510247/can-we-say-that-operatornamesuppu-cap-u-0-0/4510254#4510254)
\begin{split}
\operatorname{supp} k
&= \Bbb R^d\setminus\bigcup\big\{O\,:\, \text{$O$ is open and $k=0$ a.e. on $O$}\big\}\\
&= \bigcap\big\{ \Bbb R^d\setminus O\,:\, \text{$O$ is open and $k=0$ a.e. on $O$}\big\}. 
\end{split}

Let $u:\Bbb R^d\to \Bbb R$ be measurable. Assume that

- $k$ is symmetric, i.e. $k(x)=k(-x)$.
- $k(x)>0$ for all $x\in \operatorname{supp}k$.
- $u=0$ a.e. $\Bbb R^d\setminus\Omega_k$ and  $u=0$ a.e. $\Omega$.
- 

$$I=\iint\limits_{\Omega \Omega_k}|u(y)|^2k(x-y)d y dx=0.$$

**Question:** Prove or disprove that $u=0$ a.e. on $\Bbb R^d$ that is, we do have
$u=0$ a.e. on $\Omega_k\setminus \Omega$?

Note that when $supp k=\Bbb R^d$ we easily have $u=0$ a.e. on $\Bbb R^d$. Indeed, in this case we get $\Omega_k= \Omega+\Bbb R^d= \Bbb R^d$ and hence

$$I=\iint\limits_{\Omega \Bbb R^d}|u(y)|^2k(x-y)d y dx= \iint\limits_{\Omega \Bbb R^d}|u(x+h)|^2k(h)d h dx=0.$$
Then we pick $a\in \Omega$ such that
$$\int_{\Bbb R^d}|u(a+h)|^2k(h)d h=0.$$
Since $k>0$ on $\Bbb R^d$ we $u(a+h)=0$ for almost every $h\in \Bbb R^d$ and thus $u=0$ a.e. on $\Bbb R^d$.

**General observations** Note that $x-y\not\in supp k$ for $x\in \Omega$ and $y\not\in \Omega_k$. Thus $k(x-y)=0$ for $x\in \Omega$ and $y\not\in \Omega_k$. This implies

$$I=\iint\limits_{\Omega \Omega_k}|u(y)|^2k(x-y)d y dx=\iint\limits_{\Omega \Bbb R^d}|u(y)|^2k(x-y)d y dx\\= \iint\limits_{\Omega \Bbb R^d}|u(x+h)|^2k(h)d h dx= \iint\limits_{\Omega \operatorname{supp} k}|u(x+h)|^2k(h)d h dx$$